# Direct link to googlemaps with place id or other data from placeservice

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I use googles placeservice to find different things near some locations... like supermarkets, public transport and so on...

I'd like to open a new window showing the place directly on maps.google.

I can do this with the lat/lng:

https://www.google.dk/maps/@56.045495,10.085505,14z?hl=da

It gets the geography right, but I'd like to make it show the specific location, like this which if found using the search on the map:

https://www.google.dk/maps/place/Fakta/@56.045495,10.0833163,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x464c6993abe3de79:0xc036fb2b139e55de?hl=da

I more or less recognize the coordinate, but cannot recreate the data-part

So - how to create a direct link from the placeservice data?

Example data:

```
 {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 56.04549499999999,
               "lng" : 10.085505
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "f4c0b42302c72de733cd130f6589b2142de4f1e7",
         "name" : "Fakta",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 250,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109513446981677175720\"\u003eFakta\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "raw_reference" : {
                  "fife_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zqiScJc18CQ/VTab-hXG8XI/AAAAAAAAAAQ/hwgNgYHwxMI/k/"
               },
               "width" : 250
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJed7jq5NpTEYR3lWeEyv7NsA",
         "reference" : "CmRZAAAAAzaJO9Ozk3HNrAoVShZdMa2112V_2lh9Pj4p-_EmjqrDdeUtb81vOQGQ29A2LIlRTfyOriRssdKDKA39T9AKfIgQpg196jnKwP0kEX_O3pnZKroB6iAthowx9xz8FmSLEhDGbQEtuJZadYXCYvw3euRoGhT9i_8nJqSdku-WX3GimtT2c69syw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "store",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "Solbjerg Hedevej 25, Solbjerg"
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a [Place Details Request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) with the `place_id`:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJed7jq5NpTEYR3lWeEyv7NsA&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

The response includes a `url` field:

```
   "result" : {
      // ... snip ...
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=13850533866455848414",
```

That URL takes you directly to the place on Google Maps: https://maps.google.com/?cid=13850533866455848414.

Comment: I knew it! Would be stupid if it wasn't doable in some way..... an extra lookup but nonetheless. Thanks.

Comment: Accepted you perfectly good answer, though I had to go make an actual map implementation to get more control over the resulting map. :-)